# How to Create a VM on GCP using Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jenkins-pipeline

I tried to create a VM using gcloud directly in pipeline with this command,

pipeline {

```
      agent any

      stages{

          stage('Create a VM'){
                   gcloud compute instances create centos-7 --image-family=centos-7 --image-project=centos-cloud  --zone=europe-west2-c

                        }
               } 
  }
```

I tried passing auth-key but not finding the correct syntax to do it, can anyone help?

Comment: Your question needs a lot more details on context, execution environment and setup. Did you create the Jenkins credentials for Google Cloud: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/using-jenkins-for-distributed-builds-on-compute-engine#create_plugin_credentials

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is a next, even though there are a bunch of other steps to follow to achieve the connection and be able to create the machine, please follow this guide [Using Jenkins for distributed builds on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/using-jenkins-for-distributed-builds-on-compute-engine), which among such mentioned step we will show you a code example:

```
export PROJECT=$(gcloud info --format='value(config.project)')
cat > jenkins-agent.json <<EOF
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "googlecompute",
      "project_id": "$PROJECT",
      "source_image_family": "ubuntu-2004-lts",
      "source_image_project_id": "ubuntu-os-cloud",
      "zone": "us-central1-a",
      "disk_size": "10",
      "image_name": "jenkins-agent-{{timestamp}}",
      "image_family": "jenkins-agent",
      "ssh_username": "ubuntu"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "inline": ["sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y default-jdk"]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```